# A question about 2 degree polynomial with particular roots

Tags: polynomials

Consider the polynomial:

$4\cdot x^2+4\cdot x +1-44721^2=0$

Roots of this polynomial are - 22361 and + 22360.

My question is:

there are infinitely many 2 degree polynomials with roots - (m+1) and m, for some integer m>0?

Comment: Obviously, yes.

Answer (score 1):

We can explicitly *construct* a quadratic polynomial with roots $-(m+1)$ and $m$:
$$(x-m)(x+m+1)=0$$
Hence there are indeed infinitely many such polynomials.